# About conversion of neutrinos to photons

Tags: particle-physics, photons, standard-model, neutrinos

Photons have the ability to convert into electron and electron have the ability to convert into photons. Can this property be found among neutrinos? Is there any method to convert neutrinos into photons or vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

> Photons have the ability to convert into electron and electron have the ability to convert into photons.

This is not correct. Photons, in the  electric field of a nucleus can produce [a pair of positive and negative particles,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) because charge is a conserved quantum number in particle physics.

[image: pair prod]

[Electrons when accelerated or](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211438/why-bremsstrahlung-occurs-only-with-the-nuclei-why-not-with-the-electrons/211454) decelerated can produce photons

That is the correct framework

> Can this property be found among neutrinos? Is there any method to convert neutrinos into photons or vice versa?

Again you are hand waving a misunderstanding of how particles interact and are created.

A neutrino interaction is a [weak interaction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html), not an electromagnetic one. Thus it can only proceed through higher order diagrams, where both weak and electromagnetic vertices take part. A neutrino interacting with a nucleon can give a photon + other particles , and a photon interacting with a particle can give a neutrino +other particles, because there are quantum numbers to be conserved in the creation and annihilation of particles.

Answer (score 0):

No.  A neutrino is a particle with no charge.  A photon, on the other hand, it only able to create an electron and a positron, a muon and an antimuon, or a proton and an anti-proton via the process known as [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production).

Comment: Photons can pair produce many more particles than the ones you've listed, if they have sufficient energy. For instance, pair production of pions and taus.

Comment: Yes, but I was just trying to say that it splits into a positive and negative particle.

Comment: It forms a Z boson, a virtual particle

Comment: Huh? What does?

Comment: Oh he asked a qn and deleted it